# Formatting images in CSS div table

Tags: html, css, css-tables

I'm still learning CSS and page formatting and stuck. Would really appreciate some help.

To make this short here is what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

And this is what I'm getting instead:

[image]

I seem to have tried everything. Here is the code:

```
<div class="header-parent">

<div class="header-first-column">
  <div class="header-cell" id="header-img1">
  <img src="../../Content/images/header/header_img1.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="header-cell" id="header-img2">
  <img src="../../Content/images/header/header_img2.jpg" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="header-second-column">

 <div class="header-cell" id="header-img3">
 <img src="../../Content/images/header/header_img3.jpg" />
 </div>
 <div class="header-cell" id="header-img4">
 <img src="../../Content/images/header/header_img4.jpg" />
 </div>

</div>

<div class="header-third-column">
    <div class="header-cell" id="header-img5">
    <img src="../../Content/images/header/header_img5.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>

<div class="header-fourth-column">
    <div class="header-cell" id="header-img6">
    <img src="../../Content/images/header/header_img6.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="header-cell" id="header-img7">
    <img src="../../Content/images/header/header_img7.jpg" />
    </div>
</div>
```

And CSS:

```
.header-parent
{
    width:900px;
    top:10px;
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    }

.header-first-column
{
    width:219px;
    background-color:White;
    float:left;
    display:block;
}


.header-second-column
{
    width:285px;
    background-color:White;
    float:left;
    display:block;
}

.header-third-column
{
    width:158px;
    background-color:White;
    float:left;
    display:block;
}


.header-fourth-column
{
    width:220px;
    background-color:White;
    float:left;
    display:block;
}
```

The images themselves I tried formatting with their IDs directly such as:

```
#header-img1
{
    padding:0 0 0 0;
    text-align:center;
}
```

I tried adding margins, padding, floating images left. Nothing seems to work.
Help?

Comment: Give padding (left, right, top, bottom) to every class. Try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add some margin to the `<div>`

```
.header-second-column, .header-third-column, .header-fourth-column
{
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that did half of the trick. Why can't I move images vertically ? I want to make that white space between the two images bigger. changing margins or padding on the div#ids for those images doesn't affect them at all for some reason...

Comment: the `<img>` need to be `display: block;`, then you can add margin to them.

Comment: FOr some reason I'm seeing background through spaces between images instead of "white" would you happen to know how to fix it ?
background:#fffffff; on header divs doesn't fix it

Comment: not sure, but I've just seen that `<div class="header-parent">` is not closed in the code you provided.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add this in CSS:

```
.header-cell {
    margin: 5px;
}
```

change the value of margin in pixels depending on your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

it seems you forgot some s in between 
use below structure

```
<div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
  <div></div>
  <div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you talking about the closing div for header-parent ?